# How can I get multiple Xpaths from a website with Selenium using "contains"?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I’m learning web scraping by gathering all the company names on [this online business directory](https://www.canpages.ca/list.jsp?ct=M5H%203B7&na=Banks) and have summarized the html I’m accessing below:

```
<div id="results-panel” class=”results jsResultsList”>

           <div id="result-id-1" class="result result—highlighted result—featuredspot jsLink" data-cardid="7956141" data-list="business" data-href="pageurl">

           <div id="result-id-2" class="result jsLink" data-cardid="102395615" data-list="business" data-href="pageurl">

                   <div class="result__head">

                       <h2>

                           <a class="result__name" href="/pageurl" title="View Canadian Western Bank’s profile" onmousedown="utag.link({link_name:'busname', link_attr1:'in_listing', position_number:'l_2', listing_link:'102395615_none|busname_banks', headdir_link:'00122200|999998,00122200|107555,00122200|109235'})">Canadian Western Bank</a>

                      </h2>
```

Using Selenium IDE I was able to identify that the names share a "result-id-" Xpath, with each listing going up by 1 (26 altogether to reflect 26 results on the page):

```
Result 1 = xpath=//div[@id='result-id-1']/div[2]/h2/a = "Citibank Canada"

Result 2 = xpath=//div[@id='result-id-2']/div/h2/a = "Canadian Western Bank"

Result 3 = xpath=//div[@id='result-id-3']/div/h2/a = "BMO Bank of Montreal"
```

So I tried to use a “contains” approach, which appears to show up on all the google search results, but no luck as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox

browser.get(‘ https://www.canpages.ca/list.jsp?ct=M5H+3B7&na=Banks’)

test = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'result-id-')]")

for x in range(len(test)):
print(test[x])
```

Unfortunately, this gave me 26 instances of the below message error message (one for each of the 26 results on each page I assume, though I have never seen a blue error message before...):

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="random string", 
element="random string")>
```

This is a real head scratcher. It’s like the system knows the results are there but refuses to release them…

Comment: I am not familiar with Selenium-Python bindings, but you probably want something like `print(test[x].text)`.

Comment: This gave the results!  Thank you so much!  If you submit it as an answer, I can flag it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like "print(x.text)" did the trick!